# 'Pipenv interpreter has already been added, select "Pipenv (<project>)"...'

Tags: pycharm, pipenv

I had a Python project using Pipenv in PyCharm, which I have removed, and now when I try to create a new project at the same location, I get the following error:

> Pipenv interpreter has already been added, select "Pipenv ()" in your in...

Unfortunately the error is truncated right in the middle so I cannot read the rest.

I presume pipenv pollutes the environment so there must be some rogue files/directories left around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. In CLI, cd to project directory, exit pipenv w/ 'exit' if necessary, and run pipenv --rm to remove virtualenv
2. Back in PyCharm, hit 'Cancel' to return to 'Welcome to PyCharm' screen.
3. Select 'Configure' dropdown.
4. Select 'Settings'.
5. Under 'Project Interpreter' section, to the right of 'Project Interpreter' dropdown, select gear icon.
6. Select 'Show All...'.
7. Select virtualenv from list. NOTE: In my case, virtualenv name is prepended with '[invalid]'.
8. Hit '-' (Remove) button.
9. Hit 'OK'.
10. Hit 'OK' again from 'Settings for New Projects' screen. NOTE: In my case, this initially didn't fix and caused PyCharm to hang at splash screen on restart. A system restart cleared this up.
11. Create project as initially attempted.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM:
[image]

SOLUTION: Open any project, go to Files -> Settings -> Project Interpreter -> Python Interpreter, then remove the pipenv project ex (PIPENV (servebees))
[image]

RESULT: Viola! You can create new project at the same location.
[image]

Comment: Downvoted because it's just a picture version of accepted answer.